# Monotouch: any ideas why sending mail is sporadic?

Tags: xamarin.ios

This is the code:  d59516457">http://monobin.com/_d59516457

These are the results when using Debug|iPhone (Debug|Simulator works fine):

When the "From" is set to GMail, I can only send to a GMail account.

When the "From" is set to my ISP, I can send to myself (at the ISP) and GMail, but NOT to another of my email addresses not connected to the ISP. (it's to an address for one of my websites, which is then forwarded to my ISP).

Any ideas why this is so flakey?  I thought at first it was the ISP, but now I'm not so sure.. is there a way to "trace" any of hops?

I'm concerned that if I submit it to the app store, a user will have the same problem as this, and I don't want a bad rep for the app.  On the other hand, because it works, sometime and not others, maybe I could hope it's my phone?

Answer (score 0):

if you want you can use http://testflightapp.com/ so you get some beta testers doing Ad-Hoc releases of your app (you choose who you want to invite), if you want so I can send you an invite I would be more than glad to help you to test your app :) email me if you want the invite, my email its on my profile

About the solution, you can check if you have a webmail based interface that you can view on your computer, the email that you sent from the iPhone must be on the sent items folder, if the email and the attachment are there you can be sure that your application is delivering correctly you email to the SMTP server so the problem resides somewhere else...

Also make sure your that your smtp server is not blacklisted as a SPAM server even more if your smtp server relies on shared enviroment like Hostgator shared plans etc

Alex

Comment: I'll second that offer - I'll be happy to beta test your app.

Comment: Hi Alex... got it working with the exception of sending to GMail accounts... I suspect they are blocking it, but if the sender is using GMail, it's working.  That will do for me.

I will probably take you up on the Ad Hoc testing offer, when the app is ready.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: no worries :) I'm glad I could help and yeah when you are ready just drop me a line and I will give it a try for sure :D